# End of counting - 'Click Counter'

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm working on simple 'Click Countdown' application, which basically has an imagebutton function, which when pressed, displays the number of clicks from 10 to 9, 8, 7,... to 0. I have an issue finding how to change an imagebutton and stop counting when number of cliks will be 0.

This is the code I have so far:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import com.example.testapp.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton button1;
    TextView textView1;
    int counter = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton imageButton;
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter--;
                textView1.setText(""+ counter);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ClickListener` to the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (counter >= 0) {
        counter--;
        textView1.setText("" + counter);
    } else if (counter == 0){
        button1.setImageResource(R.id.yourdrawable);
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Also make sure to actually set button1:

```
button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value of `counter` for the zero condition.  For example, inside your `onClick` method:

```
if (counter == 0) {
    //do something else, or do nothing
} else {
    counter--;
    textView1.setText(""+counter);
}
```